# Div element won't be positioned right

Tags: internet-explorer, html

This website is built by tables and changing stuff is usually making it worse. However, I needed to change the table content with divs (from the legend text to the orange image in the bottom).

As you will notice, only IE is placing the right menu wrong. But there should be enough space. I tried [if IE] hacks, but it didn't have the desired effect.

What am I doing wrong?

On this page: http://www.selandia-ceu.dk/Selandia/Gymnasierne_p%C3%A5_Selandia/Test.aspx

(Don't bother commenting the rest of the site. It's flawed beyond count). :)

Comment: You have console errors. Try to clear them

Answer (score 0):

Your page has lots of errors which need to be cleared first.

One of the errors makes IE set the layout width for the gym-content to 100% (see in Layout tab with F12 in IE). Because of that, there's no room for the navigation to float on the right side.

Comment: What makes IE see the width as 100%? And is it height/width?

Is this the main reason for the positioning problem? Theres a new website on the way, so the rest of the site is not relevant for me. I just need this bit to work.

Comment: Choose one: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.selandia-ceu.dk%2FSelandia%2FGymnasierne_p%25C3%25A5_Selandia%2FTest.aspx&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0